# Why does DELETE statement fail silently with MySQL Connector/net when it works in MySql Workbench and PHP/PDO?

Tags: c#, mysql, mono, connector-net

I have a MariaDB database containing a table with information about mobile devices (both android and ios) running on a CentOS 7 server with Mono JIT compiler version 5.4.0.201 and MySql Connector/NET (latest version 8.0.13).

All is working great, except I can't delete devices based on push tokens from the Devices table via Connector/NET. Table definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Devices` (
  `idDevices` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `notificationId` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deviceId` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `isAndroid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `deviceModel` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `appMajor` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `appMinor` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDevices`),
  UNIQUE KEY `isAndroid` (`isAndroid`,`deviceId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `notificationId_UNIQUE` (`isAndroid`,`notificationId`),
  KEY `appVersion` (`appMajor`,`appMinor`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I run the DELETE statement from my Mono application, no exceptions occur, but the int value returned from ExecuteNonQuery() is always 0, and no rows have been deleted from the table. No errors or warnings are logged in mariadb.log (log_warning=4).
If I copy the exact same SQL statement to MySql Workbench and execute the statement there, the rows are deleted as expected.
If I create a PHP script and use PDO connection to the same db, it also works as expected. All three test cases use the same user (root). So it seems to be a problem specific to Connector/NET

```
            var tokenCount = 0;
            var sql = new StringBuilder ("DELETE FROM Devices WHERE isAndroid = 0 AND notificationId IN ('");

            while (...) {
                sql.Append (token);
                sql.Append ("','");
                tokenCount++;
            }

            sql.Length -= 2;
            sql.Append (')');

            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection (connectionString)) {
                connection.Open ();
                using (var command = new MySqlCommand (sql.ToString (), connection)) {
                    var affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery ();
                    if (affectedRows != tokenCount) {
                        //Always logs affectedRows(0)
                        log.Warn ($"Remove tokenCount({tokenCount}) != affectedRows({affectedRows}). sql={sql}");
                    }
                }
            }
```

**UPDATE:** I enabled general_log and I see the correct db is initialized AND the statement is run - but the table is not changed! Output from log:

```
        3 Init DB   mydb
        3 Query DELETE FROM Devices WHERE isAndroid = 0 AND notificationId IN ('002B1C477DB4F20868D157A806DF70E05D61D3950562C03E092707CA9C5CCF23')
```

**UPDATE #2:** I tried changing the DELETE statement into a SELECT statement using the same WHERE clause, and lo and behold, no rows are returned. So it seems that the matching on notificationId is not working for some reason. Could it be an encoding issue? Why would it work in other clients but not my Connector/NET client?

Comment: I'm not sure but, from mariadb knowledge: _For the single-table syntax, the DELETE statement deletes rows from tbl_name and returns a count of the number of deleted rows. This count can be obtained by calling the ROW_COUNT() function._ [see](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/delete/) . You are not getting the affected rows count. And what is the value of sql

Comment: @KevinKouketsu as I stated, the problem is not the value returned, the problem is that no rows are deleted. So the return value is correct, but the statement is not executed.

Comment: @mjwills Example value is: "DELETE FROM Devices WHERE isAndroid = 0 AND notificationId IN ('08C2D56EFA0372DB9F533FE791B2F2E2DDFFC73D4198641E5A440BBE8BC12110')". But my problem is not with my SQL statement, as it throws no exception and it works fine in other connectors and workbench. The problem is that the statement is completely ignored silently.

Comment: In your SQL tooling, please run this query and update your question with the results - `SELECT * FROM Devices WHERE isAndroid = 0 AND notificationId IN ('08C2D56EFA0372DB9F533FE791B2F2E2DDFFC73D4198641E5A440BBE8BC12110')" `

Comment: @mjwills Output is: `# idDevices, notificationId, deviceId, isAndroid, deviceModel, appMajor, appMinor
'3471957', '08C2D56EFA0372DB9F533FE791B2F2E2DDFFC73D4198641E5A440BBE8BC12110', '8C3ED1E7-1292-4675-8749-499AB625CDA2', '0', 'iPhone8,1', '4', '7'`

Comment: You are 100% sure you are connected to the right database?

Comment: @mjwills Yes 100% positive, the connection string is correct.

Comment: Strange, perhaps enable [full query logging](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/general-query-log/) & compare the .Net call with the Workbench call

Comment: @AlexK. This gets even stranger now.. I enabled general_log and I see that the correct db is initialized AND the query is run ... but the rows are still not deleted from the table!
`3 Init DB mydb
      3 Query DELETE FROM Devices WHERE isAndroid = 0 AND notificationId IN ('002B1C477DB4F20868D157A806DF70E05D61D3950562C03E092707CA9C5CCF23')`

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found the problem after hours of debugging. Turns out it has nothing to do with Connector/NET. The problem was in how I was constructing the tokens, I accidentally appended some characters which would not print in my log4net log, so the SQL seemed OK on the client side-- but the actual SQL string which was sent to the database server contained invalid tokens!